# Android: What is the opposite of RESULT_OK

Tags: android

What if the result is not OK,

What can I use instead for RESULT_OK when the result is not oK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RESULT_CANCELED`, if it was canceled, or any other value you fancy (as long as it is `RESULT_FIRST_USER` or higher). The activity retrieving that value will need to understand your custom value.